# Ask. How to mention the sender and the person they mentioned (discord py.)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I tried to do it in different ways, but none gave the desired result. I need to use it in an **embed**.

I am new to this area and have not found any information.

[image: What I want to achieve]

Screenshot translation:
`@name spit @name`

Comment: Can you be more precise please? I don't understand what you want to do... Can you share some code, what you tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explain your question a bit more and show code you have tried, you can use {ctx.author.mention} to mention the member that used the command and {member.mention} to mention the member that was @ make sure to call the member by useinf member :discord.Member in your async def ( )

Example:

```py
async def hi(ctx, member : discord.Member):
  await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} said hi to {member.mention}")
```

Comment: THANKSSSS!!!! this is what I needed!